# Writing a dict list as rows in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a simple csv file:

```
101,8
102,10
102,6
103,5
104,0
```

with duplicated entries for row[0] on the second and third line and I want to keep the last (or lower row[1] value) duplicate.  The only way I have figured out how to make it work correctly was using a dict() to sort, but now I am having problems writing to a csv file with the correct format.  My code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint
import csv

with open('cards1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    with open('cards2.csv', 'wb') as csvfile1:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile1, delimiter=',')
        rows = iter(reader)
        sort_key = itemgetter(0)
        sorted_rows = sorted(rows, key=sort_key)
        unique_rows = dict((row[0], row) for row in sorted_rows)
        pprint (unique_rows) 
        writer.writerows(unique_rows)
```

which prints:

```
{'101': ['101', '8'],
 '102': ['102', '6'],
 '103': ['103', '5'],
 '104': ['104', '0']}
```

but writes to my files as:

```
1,0,2
1,0,3
1,0,1
1,0,4
```

where as I would like it to simply remove the duplicate in row[0] with the largest value in row[1].  Thanks (btw, the order of the created csv is not critical)

Comment: `writer.writerows(unique_rows.values())` -- assuming the order in which the rows are printed out does not matter.

Comment: I'm confused about what you'd like the results to be. You say you want "the largest value in `row[1]`" - I only see a single value at `row[1]`. From your first csv file example are you expecting just the values of `8, 10, 6, 5, 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly.

Instead of:

```
writer.writerows(unique_rows)
```

you want to do something like:

```
for row in unqiue_rows.values():
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: That was it!  I had left off the "values()" when I had tried that statement earlier.  Thanks!  Having them sorted is not a big deal ATM, but as I'm still learning this language, I will be working on that solution next.  I was trying to solve this solution with  'sort()'  but ran into problems.